# PHP - How do I access values from other functions inside a class without using GLOABL?

Tags: php, global

I am creating this PHP class, I am having trouble accessing values that have been modified by functions inside my class. When I try to execute the `load_widgets()` function it returns `NULL`, but when I try a `var_dump()` in the `store_widget()` function, it shows the array I need. Do I have to use `global` in this case? How would I fix this problem without using `global` if possible?

```php
<?php

namespace Stuff\Widgets;

function fetch_widgets(){
    $widgets_include = require CUSTOM_PATH . 'Widgets.php';
    return $widgets_include;
}

class Widgets {

    public static $widget_array_default;
    public static $widget_array_modified;

    public static function store_widget($array){
        self::$widget_array = fetch_widgets();
        array_push(self::$widget_array, $array);
        self::$widget_array_modified = self::$widget_array_default;
        die(var_dump(self::$widget_array)); //Returns the values I need.
    }

    public static function load_widgets(){
        die(var_dump(self::$widget_array_modified)); // Returns NULL, still returns NULL if I use self::$widget_array_default
    }

}

?>
```

Comment: any reason you're using static class?

Comment: `die()` terminates the script. It can't return anything.

Comment: It seems like you're confusing `die()` with `return`.

Comment: well, probably you are not passing any data to $widget_array_default and $widget_array_modified.